# Is it possible to get compiler version from the bytecode and smart contract code?

Tags: solc, compilation, opcode

The problem is that I have deployed some contract on the etherscan.io some time ago. Now I want to verify it, so I need to specify:

1. Smart contract code
2. Compiler version
3. ABI encoded constructor arguments

But I have forgotten, which version of the compiler I have used. Probably it was between 0.4.13 and 0.4.16. So there's a small difference between bytecode inside the Ethereum blockchain and the bytecode, I'm getting now.

Is it possible to get the version of my compiler? Probably this data doesn't appear on the blockchain, but maybe there is a tool, which can analyze OPCODES, etc.

Comment: I don't think there's an existing tool for this, but you can find out what date the contract was deployed and check the Solidity GitHub repo to see what the latest release was on that date. Most likely that's what you used